# How to enter NULL into database table cell in MS Visual Studio table editor?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, null

How to enter `NULL` value into database table cell in MS Visual Studio table editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

select the cell you want to insert `NULL` then

```
CTRL + 0
```